# jquery form wizard validation

Tags: jquery, validation, formwizard

I'm trying to implement a validation script (bassistance) with a jquery form wizard (http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx) but I'm having some problems.

On the page for the jquery wizard, a guy named "Tommy" came up with a piece of code to implement bassistance with the code. But for some reason I can't get it to work. It comes up saying if the field needs to be filled in etc and the next button doesn't work - which is fine, BUT, if I fill in all the fields, the next button still doesn't work..

```
function createNextButton(i) {

            var stepName = "step" + i;
            $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<a href='#' id='" + stepName + "Next' class='next'>Next ></a>");

            /* VALIDATION */
            if (options.validationEnabled) {
                var stepIsValid = true; 
                $("#" + stepName + " :input").each(function(index) { 
                    stepIsValid = !element.validate().element($(this)) && stepIsValid;
                });
                if (!stepIsValid) {
                    return false; 
                }
            }
            /* END VALIDATION */

            $("#" + stepName + "Next").bind("click", function(e) {
                $("#" + stepName).hide();
                $("#step" + (i + 1)).show();
                if (i + 2 == count)
                    $(submmitButtonName).show();
                selectStep(i + 1);
            });

        }
```

Could someone help me figure this one out? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I added the validation to the click event and I figured out that "element.validate().element($(this)) && stepIsValid" actually existed.. If anyone else is using this and having the same problem, the solution is:

```
/* VALIDATION */
                if (options.validationEnabled) {
                    var stepIsValid = true;
                    $("#"+stepName+" :input").each(function(index) {
                        checkMe = element.validate().element($(this));
                        //stepIsValid = !element.validate().element($(this)) && stepIsValid;
                        stepIsValid = checkMe && stepIsValid;
                    });
                    //alert("stepIsValid === "+stepIsValid);
                    if (!stepIsValid) {
                        return false;
                    };
                }; 
                /* END VALIDATION */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the validation into the click event

```
function createNextButton(i) {
    var stepName = "step" + i;
    $("#" + stepName + "commands").append("<a href='#' id='" + stepName + "Next' class='next'>Next ></a>");

    $("#" + stepName + "Next").bind("click", function(e) {
        /* VALIDATION */
        if (options.validationEnabled) {
            var stepIsValid = true; 
            $(this).closest("fieldset").find(":input").each(function(index) { 
                stepIsValid = element.validate().element($(this)) && stepIsValid;
            });
            if (!stepIsValid) {
                return false; 
            }
        }
        /* END VALIDATION */

        $("#" + stepName).hide();
        $("#step" + (i + 1)).show();
        if (i + 2 == count)
            $(submmitButtonName).show();
        selectStep(i + 1);
    });
}
```

**Update**

OR... Try removing the default check from the **Receive Newsletters?** checkbox (unchecked by default).
The click event isnt getting attached to the next button because the checkbox is required and checked, so `stepIsValid` is false and createNextButton returns false before binding the click event.

Comment: Naw, it's not working either. I first got the error for $(this).closest.. so I changed it back to the original validation code and it shows what fields are required when you hit next, but once you fill in the fields and hit next again, it doesn't do anything..