# jQuery match regexp

Tags: jquery, validation

Let's say i have the following text input:

```
<input class="required-field" type="text" name="create-user-username" pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" />
```

Somewhere in my JS i (would like to) use the follow snippet in my form validation:

```
$('.required-field').each(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var pattern = $(this).attr('pattern');

    if (pattern !== 'undefined') {
        if (inputVal.match(pattern)) {
            alert('Input is not valid');
        }        
    }

});
```

However, the match is not working and I have failed in finding a working solution...

The form is completed by the user in steps, and each pages are validated before you can move to next step. That why I'm not using jQuery .validate....

Comment: Possible solution using jquery.validate in a wizard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046767/jquery-form-wizard-validation

Comment: There is error in your JS. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ` on the line `if (inputVal.match(pattern) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pattern` is a string, thus is needs to be:

```
$(this).attr('pattern').replace(/\//g,"");

if (!inputVal.match(new RegExp(pattern))) { // also you missed a ! for negation
```

also, use either

```
if (!pattern) // uses falsyness of "undefined" - also catches the empty string

// or

if ( typeof pattern !== "undefined")
```

and fix your mismatching parens: if `(inputVal.match(pattern) // <- missing )`

Comment: Wow just noticed this a second ago too, +1 @Christoph

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkvFG/)

You are missing a parenthesis.

```
if (inputVal.match(pattern)) // <-- this one
```

And as @Christoph had mentioned you are trying to match against a `string`, and can either use the `.replace()` method to remove the outer `/ /`, or change your pattern in the input element itself to be:

`input pattern="^[0-9]+$"`

And change your pattern variable to:

```
var pattern = new RegExp($(this).attr('pattern')); // now it'll all work
```

On a side note, always make sure you check your console log (you would have seen the typical `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Also when checking for undefined, the best way is to do:

**`typeof(pattern)`** `!== 'undefined'`

Comment: Sorry my bad ... I wrote the code directly in here untested. It's not due the missing parantheses. Using /^[0-9]+$/ as pattern, the alertbox is triggered no regardless of whether i enter a B or an 1...

Comment: @EibergDK ou need to convert your pattern into a regex, that's the initial problem. I already suspected it's not the missing parens issue;)

Comment: Yes, @Christoph beat me to it, he deserves the correct answer!

Comment: No worries, I was about to update the answer that's why I was saying you beat me!

Answer (score 0):

Currently your patterns is string and you need to convert to a real real pattern using `new RegExp()`.

Also remove slashes `/` from `pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"` which will not be required because `new RegExp()` will automatically add the slashes.

See the code,

```
<input class="required-field" type="text" name="create-user-username" pattern="^[0-9]+$" value=""/>
​ 


$('.required-field').each(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var pattern = $(this).attr('pattern');

    if (pattern != 'undefined') {
        pattern =  new RegExp(pattern)
        if (inputVal.match(pattern)){
            alert('Input is not valid');
        }        
    }

});​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/43eLD/1/